# c# how to use system reserved names as properties

Tags: c#

I have a custom class that has the following properties:

[image]

But I'm getting an error in `checked` because seems its a reserved word and I have to use it because the `Json` that I will send to client needs it.

Any clue?

Comment: Does your JSON formatter always go lower case? You could just capitalize everything.

Comment: How are you converting the object to JSON? Does the API you're using allow overriding the default name? That would be the best solution. Alternatively, is the JSON case-sensitive in this case? If not, then you can use `Checked` as the property name. Finally, it's possible you can use `@checked` here, but a) that's really a last resort, and b) that might not get serialized to JSON the way you want anyway.

Comment: Im using ASP WebAPI to send that to client

Comment: That goes lower case for me; just use `Checked` as the property name (it makes for better looking C# as well!)